# How to get the population and geographic location of a city using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

The only way I could think of is to search it in google and scrape the result using the BeautifulSoup module. So I did it:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JG7X.png)

(Sorry, my reputation isn't enough to post image directly)

Then I checked the source of the search result:
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6THWP.png)

So I wrote the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=new+york+city+population&oq=New+York+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4853j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('div', class_ = "kpd-ans kno-fb-ctx KBXm4e"))
```

The result is returned as `None`. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the geographic coordinates directly using [GeoPy](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/)

There is a Python package called [census](https://github.com/datamade/census) which wraps the US Census API. I have not tried it.